# Emailing javascript calculation totals

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I'm needing to email all of the information entered into my form plus the price total. I know how to send a form using php, but the total isn't a form field. Any ideas? Here is the link: http://www.redfivedesigns.com/mapp/estimate.html

Thanks,

Tommy

Answer (score 1):

welcome to SO. Your question will be best received if you show the method you took to approach the problem.

Your answer lies inside http://www.redfivedesigns.com/mapp/js/formcalculations.js you will need to replicate that logic based on the submitted form variables to calculate the total price. If you have the total as a hidden input you are vulnerable to people like me who surf those web pages and then manually lower the price and get a discount.

BUT if you don't care, just change http://www.redfivedesigns.com/mapp/js/formcalculations.js at the bottom from

```
divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the estimate $"+estimatePrice;
```

to

```
divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price For the estimate $"+estimatePrice+"<input type='hidden' name='totalprice' value='"+estimatePrice+"'></input>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that and I get a syntax error.

Comment: Add a double quote before the semicolon. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. That fixed the error, but your solution didn't work.